# What is the proper way to pass 'this' to an inline overridden method of a new object?

Tags: java

I used a local variable to store `this` in order to make it accessible inside an inline overriding but not feeling happy about that. Is there a more elegant way of doing that?

```
public class Tree extends Plant {
    public Tree() {
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(40), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        final Plant tree = this; // <---- here
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                tree.setA(5); // <---- and here
            }
        }));

        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `Tree.this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Tree.this`.  Since you're trying to access information about the `Tree` object inside of another class (i.e., `EventHandler`), `this` needs to be qualified so that the compiler knows what you're talking about.